# How do i solve repeating footer button in the listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new at android development. After spending some time i figured out how to make a custom listview. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notedate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- filler -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Note" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Listview is okey but at the time, i want to add a button and it should be only one.But now it's repeating.

[image]

Also if it's possible i want to put the button on the bottom of the area.

Comment: Can we have the java code implemeting the list view ?
Which view are you inflating as a custom item of your list ?
As I can see in your xml code, I'm not sure you understood how a ListView works...

Answer (score 0):

i think you're adding the entire ScrollView as your "element". May I suggest reorganizing your layout as a ListView?

take a look at:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70
at about 26 min, on how to add footers/headers to a listview